# Indian passport threads coming off, India travel in 2 weeks

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-renewals, consulates, damaged-passports

I live in US, and have a F1 Visa and an Indian passport. I am traveling to India in couple of weeks, and my passport got some wear and tear. The stitching which hold the inner pages and the cover is coming off, and only 2-3 threads are left.

Will the Indian Embassy fix that stitching problem? Can they do that?

Also, I plan on issuing a new passport. But my appearance has changed a bit, my indian address is different and my father’s name is different (only the surname). Can I apply for a tatkaal passport? I don’t care if they retain the same info and photo, but when the embassy sees my other supporting docs, they might be able to see a clear change in address, photo and father’s name.

Also, if I have a new passport, I will still have to retain my damaged passport since it has my visa stamping in it.  Immigration and customs can still stop me saying my damaged passport is severely damaged and have me reissue the damaged passport, right? Is there an easy way to get all my stamps and student visa on my new passport, without going to the embassy?

Also, I think my paasport has been marked as ‘damaged’ by the immigration last time I traveled

Comment: @MichaelHampton That question is about using a damaged passport for outbound travel, which is riskier than using it for inbound travel, particularly since the US has no exit immigration.  (The airline may still be unhappy with it though.)

Answer (score 5):

You have a number of different questions there, but I'll answer the main one: **passports can not be repaired, the only option is to replace it**.

Given your timeframe, it will likely be difficult to impossible to get the passport replaced before you leave, so your best choice is probably to try your luck (you'll be OK unless the airline complains) and get it replaced ASAP once you arrive in India.

A discreet piece of transparent tape to hold the cover together would also likely be helpful, just try to position it so that it doesn't cover any details on the bio-data page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have requested the US Consulate if they can expedite the process. I don’t want to rely on the Indian passport process.

Comment: Why would a "US Consulate" have anything to do with the replacement of an Indian passport? I suspect you mean you asked an _Indian_ Consulate in the US for assistance, which would be a reasonable step.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I presume that's what they meant, but if they're anything like most consulates, all they do is add an extra layer of bureaucracy to the regular passport process back home.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I don't disagree with your general point, but maybe they'd act, and asking seems a minor task.